# Count the number of objects returned in an Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My ajax request returns an IEnumerable UpcomingGigs, I'd like to count how many Gigs were returned per request. I've made various attempts at this, however each attempt includes a count of the property values too, and therefore not an accurate result.

Console.log(data.Length);
var count=Object.keys(data).length;

ajax data response:

  08/01/2021 17:50:00 - Bob

both values return the same incorrect result.

```
public ActionResult FetchGigs(int skip, int take)
        {
            var upcomingGigs = _context.Gigs
                                .Include(g => g.Artist)
                                .Where(g => g.DateTime > DateTime.Now)
                                .OrderBy(d => d.DateTime)
                                .Skip(skip).Take(take);

            var viewModel = new GigsViewModel
            {
                UpcomingGigs = upcomingGigs
            };
            return PartialView("FetchGigs", viewModel);
        }
```

ViewModel

Ajax

```
    public class GigsViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<Gig> UpcomingGigs { get; set; }
            public int TotalGigs { get; set; }
            public bool ShowActions { get; set; }
            public string Heading { get; set; }
        }

$(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "@Url.Action("FetchGigs")",
                        data: { skip: skip, take: take },
                        success: function (data) {

                            console.log(data.GigsViewModel.gigId.);

                            $(".result").append(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you post an example of what your response looks like?

Comment: @vlaz Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 72
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 13 May 2018 18:10:59 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcamFtZXNcc291cmNlXHJlcG9zXEdpZ2h1YjNcR2lnaHViM1xIb21lXEZldGNoR2lncw==?=

Comment: I mean the response data after the AJAX call - so, what the `data` variable has inside the `success: function (data)` block.

Comment: @vlaz oh sorry! <ul>
<li class="gig">08/01/2021 17:50:00 - Bob</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. One way is to add a data attribute the `ul` element you are rendering from the partial view and store the item count in that. You can use the `IEnumerable.Count()` method.

```
@model YourNamespace.GigsViewModel
<ul data-itemcount="@Model.UpcomingGigs.Count()">
    @foreach (var item in Model.UpcomingGigs)
    {
        <li>@item.Title</li>
    }
</ul>
```

Now in your ajax success event, parse the response received from the server using `$.parseHTML` and then reading the data attribute value

```
success: function (data) {
    var html =$.parseHTML(data);
    var itemCount = $(html).data("itemcount");
    alert(itemCount);
}
```

Another option is to use the `find` method to get the list item array and get it's length.

```
success: function(data) {
    var html = $.parseHTML(data);
    var itemCount = $(html).find("li").length;
    alert(itemCount);
}
```

I would go with the first approach as i do not like my browser doing so much of work. (It has to loop through the dom elements here to get the count)